# turtle.onclick lagging 1 cycle behind

Tags: python, onclick, turtle-graphics

When creating a turtle onclick event my clicks lags 1 click behind.
In my example I have two buttons that adds or subtracts 1 from a value, when I click one of the buttons it does the action of the last button I pushed, not the one I just clicked.

Example:

My number is 3.

- Start program.
- Click "+" -> nothing happens.
- Click "+" -> number becomes 4.
- Click "-" -> number becomes 5.
- Click somewhere blank -> number becomes 4.
- Click "+" -> nothing happens.
- Click somewhere blank -> number becomes 5.

Example code.

```
import turtle
num = 3

turtle.setup(400,500)
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("None")
wn.bgcolor("black")


# Functions for what happens clicking the minus or plus button
def num_minus(xcor, ycor):
  global num
  if num > 1:
    num = num-1
  num_disp.clear()
  num_disp.write("{}".format(num), align="center", font=("Arial", 26, "normal"))
  print(num)

def num_plus(xcor, ycor):
  global num
  if num < 9:
    num = num+1
  num_disp.clear()
  num_disp.write("{}".format(num), align="center", font=("Arial", 26, "normal"))
  print(num)

# Creating minus button, left of number
minus_btn = turtle.Turtle()
minus_btn.penup()
minus_btn.color("gray")
minus_btn.shape("square")
minus_btn.goto(-30, 0)
minus_btn.onclick(num_minus)

# Creatig plus button, right of number
plus_btn = turtle.Turtle()
plus_btn.penup()
plus_btn.color("gray")
plus_btn.shape("square")
plus_btn.goto(30, 0)
plus_btn.onclick(num_plus)

# Displays the number
num_disp = turtle.Turtle()
num_disp.penup()
num_disp.color("red")
num_disp.goto(0, -20)
num_disp.write("{}".format(num), align="center", font=("Arial", 26, "normal"))
num_disp.ht()

wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Why are my clicks 1 click behind, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was *not* able to reproduce the errant behavior you describe.  Regardless, here's some possibilities to consider:

1. On some systems, the turtle window does not come up as the *key* window and you need to click on it once (anywhere) to have it receive events.  You should be able to click between the turtle window and another window on your screen to see how the windows visually change as they gain, and lose, *key* status.  If your window needs to be clicked first to receive events, then you may be miscounting that click as a button click.
2. Your event handlers are open to receive a new event while they are still processing a previous event.  They should be disabled until they are ready for a new event to keep events from interrupting one another and messing with your count.
3. You instruct the turtle window to `listen()` to keyboard events which are not used in this interface, so don't turn that on.

Below is my rework of your code to address some of the above and restyle it -- see if it fixes any of your issues or not:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 26
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

number = 3

# Functions for what happens when clicking the minus or plus button
def number_minus(x, y):
    global number

    minus_button.onclick(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    if number > 1:
        number -= 1

        number_display.clear()
        number_display.write(number, align='center', font=FONT)

    minus_button.onclick(number_minus)  # reenable handler on exit

def number_plus(x, y):
    global number

    plus_button.onclick(None)

    if number < 9:
        number += 1

        number_display.clear()
        number_display.write(number, align='center', font=FONT)

    plus_button.onclick(number_plus)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 500)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Displays the number
number_display = Turtle()
number_display.hideturtle()
number_display.color('red')
number_display.penup()
number_display.sety(-FONT_SIZE/2)
number_display.write(number, align='center', font=FONT)

# Creating minus button, left of number
minus_button = Turtle()
minus_button.shape('triangle')
minus_button.color('gray')
minus_button.left(30)
minus_button.penup()
minus_button.setx(-30)
minus_button.onclick(number_minus)

# Creatig plus button, right of number
plus_button = Turtle()
plus_button.shape('triangle')
plus_button.color('gray')
plus_button.right(30)
plus_button.penup()
plus_button.setx(30)
plus_button.onclick(number_plus)

screen.mainloop()
```